# Cannot see leads and opportunities in sales module

Tags: openerp-7

I am using OpenERP 7. I have installed the sales management module. But I cannot see the leads and opportunities in the left sub menu.

I can only see customers, quotations and sales order. Am I wrong, and it can be found in another module?

I looked in the admin settings menu but I don't see a solution to make them visible. Do I have to get into the coding?

Answer (score 0):

Login with Admin and follow below steps.

1. Settings => Modules => Installed Modules
2. Remove filter from the right side *installed* and write `sale_crm`

[image]

3. Install this module and refresh the browse and Now move to Sales Menu, you will see the Leads and Opportunities Menu under Sales.

Hope this will help you.